# how can I force stack (haskell-stack) to never download anything?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

my workflow uses `system-ghc: true` exclusively. I want stack to fail hard anytime it would otherwise access the network to download anything. Is this possible to configure (either globally or per project would do)?

Comment: Wild guess: would `system-ghc: true` and `resolver: ghc-8.0.1` (or whatever the relevant version is) work? Otherwise, it sounds very unlikely.

Comment: There's [an open issue to add a `--offline` flag](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1594), which sounds like what you would like to have. As a workaround I'd suggest wrapping the stack command in some kind of script that prevents it from accessing the network.